# Reset focus to control with lowest tab index

Tags: vb.net, winforms

I have a form that is re-used. That is, instead of creating a new instance of the form each time, the form is kept hidden, and is made visible when needed. (A design I inherited; I presume this was a performance optimization.)

The problem: The second time that the form is used, the focus is on the OK or Cancel button, from the first use of the form.

The user wants the focus to start the way it did the first time the form appears - on the control with lowest tab index.

If there were just one such form, I would hack it: add a line of code hardwired to the desired  control.

But there are many such forms, and the visibility logic is in a common base class.

So it would make more sense to do this right, and tell the form to focus on its first (lowest tabindex) control.

Is there an easy way to do so?

(I could iterate through all the controls, but then I have to correctly handle nested controls. Since the GUI has to do this the first time it shows a form, I am hoping there is some method I can call that does it for me.)

(Coded in VB.net, but a C# answer would be fine.)

Comment: NOTE: One solution I have come up with is to add a custom field to the base class. Each subclass can set this field to the control which should be selected when the form is opened (or re-shown; made visible again). Pro: is independent of the tab indices, and sometimes that is useful. Con: is independent of the tab indices, and that is extra work and maintenance.

Comment: A second solution, that seems a bit obscure, is to have the base class distinguish between creating the form the first time, and re-using the form. The first time, I'm not sure on which event, REMEMBER which control became active. Subsequent times, SELECT (or set ActiveControl) that remembered control.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is a one-liner, the logic to find the next control is exposed as a method, [SelectNextControl()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.selectnextcontrol%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).  You should start at the Form object, the one that can never get the focus, and ask it to find the next one in the tabbing order.  Which is the child with the lowest TabIndex, whatever value it might have.

So something like this:

```
public void ShowAgain() {
    this.Show();
    this.SelectNextControl(this, true, true, true, true);
}
```

And *do* consider that a Form object that isn't visible is a rather major resource hog, using up lots of operating system resources for a small convenience.  Surely you can also Close/Dispose it and recreate it when needed.  YMMV.

Comment: There seems to be some different problem interfering with focus in my situation. Whether I use my initial code (just does Show), or use your code, and/or Jacob's code, the form2 seems to be in a strange state: for my simplest form2, a textbox with OK and cancel buttons, tabbing thru them goes thru 3 states, but when the textbox is active, it still doesn't get keyboard focus: no cursor & nothing happens when hit a key. Works fine on first appearance; this only happens on second appearance.

Comment: (Although it requires changing code in every form in this large application, I do hope to eventually dispose all the forms. I would never have implemented it this way. This might be the "minor" nit that forces me to do that code rewrite. Leary that this poorly organized code base might abuse some forms to hold data, so avoiding doing so unless I have to.)

Comment: If I click on some other window, then click back to form2, focus of the textbox magically starts working correctly. Same if I Alt-Tab to a different application, and then back.

Comment: You can put this code in an event handler for the form's Activated event.  Your user will hate you.

Comment: No, I'm saying it works great when switching between apps. So don't need to do something special on Activated. Alt-tabbing was just a random test to determine what was strange about the focus. What is peculiar is that it doesn't work UNTIL I do something that forces a second activation. However, I did try adding this to Activated, and made sure it then hits a breakpoint there. Still doesn't work until Alt-tab and back.

Comment: Yes, you are right, but this aspect of it is scattered among multiple poorly written classes (not by me), in a huge legacy application. Consider the original question answered -- both your answer and Jacob's answer DO alter which sub-control have focus. I will have to devise a new question for the focus oddity. Thank you for your time!

Answer (score 1):

You can try to set [ActiveControl](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.containercontrol.activecontrol%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) property before making form visible:

```
_frm.ActiveControl = null;
```

This should clear the active control for the form and remove focus from its controls.

Comment: As per my comment to Hans answer, this isn't helping in my case -- though is probably a good solution, once I find what is interfering with focus in my specific situation.

Comment: If I Alt-tab to another application, and then back, I do see that the textbox is active (rather than the Cancel button from first use of form2).  So this does work as advertised (if I can determine why keyboard focus is in a confused state when form2 appears when re-shown, until I Alt-tab or click to a different form and then back).

Comment: NOTE: Although I checked Hans as the answer, this solution works equally as well.